# how to add object in NSMutableArray using macro

Tags: objective-c, macros, nsmutablearray

for now i am creating my NSMutableArray using:

```
#define ARRAY_OF_ORDER_SOURCE [NSArray arrayWithObjects:DICTIONARY_OF_ORDER_SOURCE_ALL,DICTIONARY_OF_ORDER_SOURCE_ECOMMERCE,DICTIONARY_OF_ORDER_SOURCE_PHYSICAL,DICTIONARY_OF_ORDER_SOURCE_INVOICE,DICTIONARY_OF_ORDER_SOURCE_RECURRING,DICTIONARY_OF_ORDER_SOURCE_SALESVU,DICTIONARY_OF_ORDER_SOURCE_RESERVATION,nil]
```

i want to do some thing like:

```
if(somethingIstrue)
[ARRAY_OF_ORDER_SOURCE addObject:DICTIONARY_OF_ORDER_SOURCE_ALL]
if(somethingElseIstrue)
[ARRAY_OF_ORDER_SOURCE addObject:DICTIONARY_OF_ORDER_SOURCE_ECOMMERCE]
```

i am doing this as i need this array in my whole project, i have this in constant.h file.
how can i acheive this using macro??
Thanks.

Comment: why don't you add a category on NSMutableArray doing so?

Comment: @JulianKról thanks can you please give me some pointers, cant find on google.I have to control the structure of this array/mutablearray at the very first point because it is being used at multiple places, i can removeObject at index on multiple places, but instead i want to add objects conditionally only at the time of creation.Please help me

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to have a macro for this you can have a [multiline macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374107/how-to-create-a-macro-with-multiple-lines-of-code) and placed there the logic you want. It is not totally clear to me what you want to achieve but instead of macro I would prefer to have a category on NSMutableArray returning the array or some kind of Util class doing so.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous things wrong with your question. For starters, you claim you are creating an NSMutableArray, but you are in actuality creating an NSArray. You then try to addObject on the immutable array, which you cannot do.

In your line (note I modified it to add a comment):

```
if(somethingIstrue) {
    // The NSArray isn't assigned to anything and tries to addObject to an NSArray
    [ARRAY_OF_ORDER_SOURCE addObject:DICTIONARY_OF_ORDER_SOURCE_ALL]
}
```

you are not assigning the array to anything (as I already noted it won't work because it is trying to add to an NSArray).

I think you want to do something like:

```
NSMutableArray *orderedSource = [NSMutableArray array];

if (somethingIsTrue) {
    [orderedSource addObject:addObject:DICTIONARY_OF_ORDER_SOURCE_ALL];
}

if (somethingElseIsTrue) {
    [orderedSource addObject:addObject:DICTIONARY_OF_ORDER_SOURCE_ECOMMERCE];
}
```

The question you have to ask yourself is why do you insist on using a macro? You have no real design/approach here, which is why your ideas are coming across as scattered.

If you need to consistently create an array based on a set of constraints, one approach would be to create a class which can vend for you the array you want based on criteria. Or you can just do it where you need to using the approach above.